# How to allow external keyboard to work before first login (windows 10 enterprise)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I've got a laptop but most of the time it's connected to a docking station with external keyboard, mouse, and monitors.  Whenever it's a fresh boot then, at the login screen, my external keyboard and mouse don't work.  I have to open the laptop to type in my pin.  Once it logs in then the keyboard and mouse will work.  The external monitors are working so the laptop is recognizing the docking station before login so I don't think it's an order of operations thing.  Is this a security setting that I can turn off?  In other words, is there a way I can make it always accept external keyboard input whether it's a security setting or other issue?

It's Windows 10 Enterprise using a Caldigit docking station on a usb3 port.

Comment: Can you try a different keyboard?  We have used Lenovo machines on Lenovo docks with Lenovo or Logitech keyboards and keyboards work with the dock and the laptop lid closed.

Comment: I don't have an extra keyboard atm.  The issue isn't that it only works when the lid is open.  The issue is that it doesn't work until I'm logged in from a fresh boot.  Fortunately the issue is only on a fresh boot.  If it is locked from inactivity then it'll still work the next time I unlock it.